# Loading Lightbox2 from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have created a website with several divs that are loaded with jQuery. In one of the divs I have clickable image thumbs that show the images in a lightbox with the Lightbox2 script.

The problem is that when I click the link that loads the image thumbs in the div a second time, a blank lightbox appears.To make clear: the div with the image thumbs is already loaded at the second click.

I thought the error occured because I already loaded the images in the div and that the second load somehow triggered the lightbox2 script. But I am clearing that div with every click, so that shouldn't be possible.

How can I stop this from happening?

Code:

loader.js (script to show content in divs after click, #rightinfo = right div with images)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#main a[name="inner"]', function () {
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,'');
  image = new Image();
             image.src = 'timelines/' + hash + '.jpg';
  // alert(hash);
  image.onload = function () {
          $('#timeline').empty().append(image);
   $('#rightinfo').empty();
      };
  image.onerror = function () {
          $('#timeline').empty().html('Geen tijdlijn beschikbaar.');
   $('#rightinfo').empty();
  }

      $('#timeline').empty().html('Loading...');
  $('#rightinfo').empty().html('Loading...');

  $('#main').load('content/' + page);
  $('#rightinfo').load('info/' + hash + '.html');

  // $('.lijn').hide();
  // $(hash).show();  
  return false;
 });
```

Code of the html-page loaded in the rightinfo-div to show the lightbox and images:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<i>Nieuw-Beijerland in 1650</i><p>
<a href="images/Nieuw-BeijerlandDorp1650.jpg" data-lightbox="NBDorp1650"><img src="timthumb.php?src=images/Nieuw-BeijerlandDorp1650.jpg&q=100&h=150"></a><p> 

<a href="images/Nieuw-BeijerlandKerk1650.jpg" data-lightbox="NBKerk1650"><img src="timthumb.php?src=images/Nieuw-BeijerlandKerk1650.jpg&q=100&h=150"></a><p>

</body>

</html>
```

I have checked and the timthumb.php used for making the thumbs did not change the behaviour of the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Solution was to move the lightbox.js script from the html-page that was loaded into the div rightinfo with jQuery, straight into the div on the index.php page like this:

```html
<div id="rightinfo">
<script src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</div>
```

I have also removed all the html tags from the html page that gets loaded in the rightinfo div, as it did not seem to matter whether is was there or not. The htmlpage in the rightinfo div now looks like this:

```html
<link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">


<i>Nieuw-Beijerland in 1650</i><p>
<a href="images/Nieuw-BeijerlandDorp1650.jpg" data-lightbox="NBDorp1650"><img src="timthumb.php?src=images/Nieuw-BeijerlandDorp1650.jpg&q=100&h=150"></a><p> 

<a href="images/Nieuw-BeijerlandKerk1650.jpg" data-lightbox="NBKerk1650"><img src="timthumb.php?src=images/Nieuw-BeijerlandKerk1650.jpg&q=100&h=150"></a><p>
```